# recaptcha fields missing from mobius forms

Tags: 2sxc

0

Mobius Forms MobiusForms5 05.03.02 2sxc: 12.10.00 DNN: 07.04.02 Oqt: 02.02.00

and the Recapchta settings do not show :missing form fields

hoping to activate Recaptcha... but no place to enter the key I have done this before on other sites and it's not working on this new installation

unable to enter keys

Answer (score 0):

First, your 2sxc and DNN versions are very old. You should focus on upgrades as soon as possible.

Second, if I am understanding correctly, you haven't found where to put the recaptcha keys? 2sxc Apps like Mobius use App Settings. Usually, when Modius is first installed, there are instructions and links to help in setting this up.

Further, you most likely need to be logged in as a Super/Host to get to these settings. If things are working normally, when you hover on the Mobius app, you should see the Toolbars. Click the "..." button 2 or 3 times until you see the gear button, click that to launch the Admin UI, go to the App tab. In that screen you can edit all the app config, resources, and settings. It should not take too much poking around to find where the "keys" for the recaptcha settings go.

One last note, I don't understand, "do not show :missing form fields" - could you share a screenshot so we can see where that is, what it looks like?

Comment: I would like to second this - pls update 2sxc first - v12 is sooo 2020. Then - depending on the Mobius app - the values are either in App-Settings/Resources or in the more general settings. I think v5 already uses the standardized / shared settings https://docs.2sxc.org/basics/configuration/index.html